# FMX progressbar color

Tags: delphi, stylesheet, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

Please be kind, I did my best with google, and found some guidance (also on StackOverflow), but none of it works for me.

FMX form with FMX Progressbar;

I only want to change the progressbar color from ugly yellow to cool skyBlue.

So far I've dropped a stylebook on the form;

I've added "progresscellstyle.htrack.hindicator" to the stylesheet designer;

It's the only one that even provides me with a color option (vs everything in "progressbarstyle treeitem") and that color does not influence my progressbar colour.

Please, a next step to decoding this problem if you could be so kind

Answer (score 5):

Drop a TProgressBar on the form. Right click it and select Edit Custom Style. It should give you the style designer with a ProgressBar1Style1 object which contains htrack and vtrack.

htrack contains hindicator. Drop a TRectangle on the hindicator. Set the TRectangle to align Client. Change the Fill color as desired. Change the Stroke Kind to None.

vtrack contains vindicator. Drop a TRectangle on the vindicator. Set the TRectangle to align Client. Change the Fill color as desired. Change the Stroke Kind to None.

Close the style designer and save when it asks. This is one way to do it.

Comment: HI FMXe, *sigh* can't get it to work, is there maybe a programmatic way to do it, that would be the preferred way, because later on I probably would like to change the color of the progressbar when it hits 50%?

Answer (score 1):

This may be a title old question, but the content about this is so rare that I think will be useful to future generations to have some info here.

To simply put, to change the color that will fill your bar you have to select a area in your BitmapLinks. To do that double click in the SourceLink property in the hindicator (a child of htrack in the tree view).

Then select a are that you will want to use as the filling, if none of the option pleases you, you may add a new BitMap to your StyleBook.

For the background color, just insert a rectangle inside htrack with a Client Alignment